# my stylesheet says to output as xml but instead its text

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

my stylesheet says to output as xml but instead its text
Any insight?

[image]

Comment: In the transformation scenario of output parameter tab, you have to mention, what format output you want to be. if you want xml means u have to mention (123.xml, 123.xhtml, 123.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is indeed XML. To verify this, right click in the browser and select "View source...".

But unfortunately most browsers choose to display the transformed XML by only showing its text content.